# Host key verification failed SSH Github

Tags: linux, ssh, git

I've taken a relatively simple approach to try and securely clone my GitHub repo but still struggling.

On My Mac I ran specifying name as MyKey and no password

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I uploaded the contents of the public key to GitHub with read and write access. Then I ran the following commands on my server:

```
cat > /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa << EOF
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
The private key 
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF

chmod 600 /root/.ssh/github.id_rsa
    
cat > /root/.ssh/config << EOF
    Host github.com
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.id_rsa
EOF
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/config

git clone git@github.com:myname/myproject.git /var/www/test
```

However the error I get back is:

```
Cloning into '/var/www/test'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: The host key is the ssh key of the server. Ssh compares the key it had saved on first connect in known_hosts file. If it is different you get this error. Make sure the key you see is one of these https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints